# Populating dropdown based on radiobutton knockout

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am trying to populate lists based on the selection of the radio button in knockout.

Based on the radio button selection, appropriate list gets data-binded to the dropdown.
http://jsfiddle.net/varunfiddle/5r9gjbdp/   <--- this works just fine.

However when I add the value field in the data-bind attribute the second drop down list does not populate itself.

http://jsfiddle.net/varunfiddle/h77mgmx8/1/

```
<p>

<input type="radio" value="groupUsers" data-bind="checked: Select" />sel users
<input type="radio" value="allUsers" data-bind="checked: Select" />all users
</p>
<p data-bind="text: Select"></p>
<p data-bind="with: Select">
     <select data-bind="value:selU,options: $root.users[$data], optionsText:'name',optionsCaption: 'Choose'"></select><br/>
    Something else? <select data-bind="value:allU, options: $root.users[$data], optionsText:'place'  ,optionsCaption: 'Choose'"></select>
</p>


function ViewModel() {
    this.Select = ko.observable();
    this.selU= ko.observable();
    this.allU=ko.observable();
    this.users = {
        groupUsers:[{name:"Varun",place:"bangalore"},{name:"Harsha",place:"SanJose"}],
        allUsers:[{name:"Robb",place:"houstonn"},{name:"Stark",place:"London"}]
    }}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

What is the mistake that I am making ?

When I try to access the value field, I see a  null. Why is the value field not getting updated ?
http://jsfiddle.net/varunfiddle/h77mgmx8/3/

Comment: Giving  value: selU and value: allU   as  
value: 'selU' and value: 'allU' may work . Check it once.

Comment: @G_S No it does not work. In this fiddle when I try to access the value field, I see a  null. Why is the value field not getting updated ?
http://jsfiddle.net/varunfiddle/h77mgmx8/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with your second `select`, it's with the first.

Modify your `data-bind` for both:

```
<select data-bind="value:$root.selU,options: $root.users[$data], optionsText:'name',optionsCaption: 'Choose'"></select><br/>
Something else? <select data-bind="value:$root.allU, options: $root.users[$data], optionsText:'place'  ,optionsCaption: 'Choose'"></select>
```

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/h77mgmx8/5/

**Edit in response to new Fiddle**

When you created the data-binding to reference the .name, you caused the bindings to bomb out.  When you first load your models the value will be null; and .name does not exist on the null object returned from selU or allU.  Add the following to your model:

```
// Null reference exceptions kill bindings, so let's fix null to
// be an empty object.
var self = this;
ko.computed(function () {
    if (!self.selU()) {
        self.selU({});
    }
    if (!self.allU()) {
        self.allU({});
    }
});
```

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/h77mgmx8/13/

Comment: Thanks for your update. But when I try to access the values I see a blank for the second dropdown selection.

Take a look at the last two bind statements
http://jsfiddle.net/varunfiddle/h77mgmx8/8/

Comment: I just opened the fiddle I posted, and selected the first radio button, then dropped down the second list.  I can see values.  What do you see?

Comment: I am trying to access the values using text binding for the selected fields.
Take a look at the last two statements 
[link] (jsfiddle.net/varunfiddle/h77mgmx8/8)

`<p data-bind="text:allU().place">` does not work

Comment: Yes - because you're binding to selU raw in your <select>.  You need to bind to $root.selU.  Notice you're using a with: Select binding, then immediately binding to value:selU.  The problem is Select does not have a selU, only your $root model does.  That's why it's not working.  See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h77mgmx8/10/

Comment: I understood your point that the selU is with the root element. But my question is, in this link [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/varunfiddle/h77mgmx8/8/) both the selU and allU belong to the roots context. When one of selU().name works, why does the allU().place not work?

Comment: Aah - I see what you're trying to do.  See the edit to my response for an update in response to your fiddle.

Comment: Could you please paste in the the link you have mentioned about ?

Comment: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h77mgmx8/13)
 Works as expected. But can you let me know a bit more about the real problem I was facing. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Perfect ! :) I got it .. thanks a lot  .. Its quite a good point to take a note of..

Answer (score 0):

Try this  [here](http://jsfiddle.net/G_sh/h77mgmx8/12/).

Here in the fiddle we are doing

```
<p data-bind="with: Select">
 <select data-bind=" value:$root.selU ,options: $root.users[$data], optionsText:'name',optionsCaption: 'Choose' "></select>
```

As Paul mentioned you need to use $root for the value.

Every time we will use a foreach or someother logic which has a loop functionality, we tend to forget writing $root if we are referring to any observable outside that loop